# Getting errors creating ChromiumOSR programmatically

Tags: delphi, tchromium

I'm trying to create ChromiumOSR programmatically but I keep getting an error (access violation). 
Here is sample code that causes the problem:

```
var
pChromiumOSR: TChromiumOSR;
begin
  pChromiumOSR := TChromiumOSR.Create(Self);
  pChromiumOSR.OnLoadEnd := pChromiumOSRLoadEnd;
  pChromiumOSR.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl('www.google.com');
end;
```

The problem is that pChromiumOSR.Browser.MainFrame is always nil. If I do 
pChromiumOSR.load('www.google.com'); I don't get any errors but it doesn't fire the onLoadend.

Can anyone give me any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?
I'm using Delphi XE2 but not sure which version of chromium (where can I find the version?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt to use `Load` method for loading a page was correct. The other one was wrong and failed because the `Browser` instance was not created. It's because the `TChromiumOSR` was designed to be a design time component rather than to be created dynamically.

Now, the only place where the `Browser` instance is created is the `Loaded` method, which is called for a component after its parent form is loaded from a stream. And since you are creating it dynamically, the `Browser` instance is never created.

For some reason also the `CreateBrowser` method (which creates the `Browser` instance) is declared as private, which complicates its calling a bit (unless you decide to modify the source and make it public). If you don't want to change your DCEF source code, you can use a class helper to provide access to the `CreateBrowser` method:

```
uses
  ceflib, cefvcl;

type
  TChromiumOSRHelper = class helper for TCustomChromiumOSR
  public
    procedure CreateBrowserInstance;
  end;

implementation

{ TChromiumOSRHelper }

procedure TChromiumOSRHelper.CreateBrowserInstance;
begin
  Self.CreateBrowser;
end;
```

Then to create a `Browser` instance add the `CreateBrowserInstance` call before the first accessing the `Browser` instance (which is here the `Load` method):

```
var
  pChromiumOSR: TChromiumOSR;
begin
  pChromiumOSR := TChromiumOSR.Create(Self);
  pChromiumOSR.OnLoadEnd := pChromiumOSRLoadEnd;
  pChromiumOSR.CreateBrowserInstance;
  pChromiumOSR.Load('www.google.com');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks TLama, I used your example and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the quick and great answer.